# SignalR Hosting on Local Area Network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, signalr, owin, signalr-hub

I am developing winform application. It is working on two computer. MSSQLSERVER installed on main(host) computer. The program has working on main computer with no error.

I have a SignalR server(Windows Forms) that host on a computer of which IP is (192.168.1.5)

However, when i put that ip adress, program does not work. It always works on localhost why ?

```
    public partial class WinFormsClient : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This name is simply added to sent messages to identify the user; this 
    /// sample does not include authentication.
    /// </summary>
    private String UserName { get; set; }
    private IHubProxy HubProxy { get; set; }

    const string ServerURI = "http://localhost:1313/signalr";
    private HubConnection Connection { get; set; }

    internal WinFormsClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HubProxy.Invoke("Send", UserName, TextBoxMessage.Text);
        TextBoxMessage.Text = String.Empty;
        TextBoxMessage.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and connects the hub connection and hub proxy. This method
    /// is called asynchronously from SignInButton_Click.
    /// </summary>
    private async void ConnectAsync()
    {


        Connection = new HubConnection(ServerURI);
        Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;
        HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        //Handle incoming event from server: use Invoke to write to console from SignalR's thread
        HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) =>
            this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}: {1}" + Environment.NewLine, name, message))
            ))
        );

        HubProxy.On<string>("CallForReport", (message) =>
                this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}" + Environment.NewLine, message))
            ))
        );

        try
        {
            await Connection.Start();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            StatusText.Text = "Unable to connect to server: Start server before connecting clients.";
            //No connection: Don't enable Send button or show chat UI
            return;
        }

        //Activate UI
        SignInPanel.Visible = false;
        ChatPanel.Visible = true;
        ButtonSend.Enabled = true;
        TextBoxMessage.Focus();
        RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText("Connected to server at " + ServerURI + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the server is stopped, the connection will time out after 30 seconds (default), and the 
    /// Closed event will fire.
    /// </summary>
    private void Connection_Closed()
    {
        //Deactivate chat UI; show login UI. 
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => ChatPanel.Visible = false));
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => ButtonSend.Enabled = false));
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => StatusText.Text = "You have been disconnected."));
        this.Invoke((Action)(() => SignInPanel.Visible = true));
    }

    private void SignInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserName = UserNameTextBox.Text;
        //Connect to server (use async method to avoid blocking UI thread)
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
        {
            StatusText.Visible = true;
            StatusText.Text = "Connecting to server...";
            ConnectAsync();
        }
    }

    private void WinFormsClient_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Connection != null)
        {
            Connection.Stop();
            Connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to change localhost to (192.168.1.5:1313)
After that, I would like to recivemessage from client to server.

Client 1 IP is (192.168.1.5)
Client 2 IP is (192.168.1.20)

SignlaR Hub + MSSQLSERVER + Client1 in the same computer.

Comment: On client 1, open cli and run `nestat -ano`, check if sth is listening on port 1313. If there is, ensure that firewall software is disabled (since SignalR is TCP, you can test connectivity by opening cli on Client 2 and running `telnet 192.168.1.5 1313`)

Comment: telnet command not working on windows 10

Comment: '/nestat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: it's `neTstat`, apologies had a typo. For telnet you need to install it from `Control Panel` Add Windows features